# Regex problem : sorting Chinese Hanzi and pinyin

Tags: regex, libreoffice

I am trying to sort groups of Hanzi and pinyin into correct order. E.g.

得到, 取得, 收到, 拿到, 获得 dédào, qǔdé, shōudào, nádào, huòdé.

=>
得到 dédào, 取得 qǔdé, 收到 shōudào, 拿到 nádào, 获得 huòdé.

I am using Libreoffice for this purpose, which accepts regex expressions. Problem is, I don't how to write the suitable regex expressions.

So far I have created this:
^([一-龥]+)[,]
which puts $1=得到
(which is fine)

Remaining problems :
 1. How to identify the rest of Hanzi groups,
    i.e. put $2=取得, $3=收到 etc.
    Number of Hanzi groups varies line by line.

2. How to identify the pinyin groups seperately, i.e.
   put $a=dédào $b=qǔdé etc. (or in some other ways   distinct from the Hanzi groups)
3. How to write the replace string so it will create:
   得到 dédào, 取得 qǔdé, 收到 shōudào, 拿到 nádào, 获得 huòdé.

Screenshots of the problem:

[image: Screenshot of the problem 1]
[image: Screenshot of the problem 2]

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in the question comments:

"The problem is not specifically related to Libreoffice. Instead, it's about how to form proper regex expressions",

I chose to solve this question using Python. Python can do this using regular expressions, together with zhon (https://zhon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import re

from zhon import hanzi, pinyin

text = "得到, 取得, 收到, 拿到, 获得 dédào, qǔdé, shōudào, nádào, huòdé."
target = "得到 dédào, 取得 qǔdé, 收到 shōudào, 拿到 nádào, 获得 huòdé."

hanzi_char = re.findall('[%s]' % hanzi.characters, text)
pinyin_word = re.findall(pinyin.word, text, re.I)

print(f"{text = }")

print(f"{hanzi_char = }")
print(f"{pinyin_word = }")

comb_hanzi_char = [i + j
                   for i, j in zip(hanzi_char[0:10:2],
                                   hanzi_char[1:11:2]
                                  )
                   ]

print(f"{comb_hanzi_char = }")

res = [hanzi + ' ' + pinyin
       for hanzi, pinyin in zip(comb_hanzi_char, pinyin_word)
       ]

res = ', '.join(res) + '.'

print(f"\n{target = }")
print(f"{res = }")

assert(res == target)
```

Returns:

```
text = '得到, 取得, 收到, 拿到, 获得 dédào, qǔdé, shōudào, nádào, huòdé.'
hanzi_char = ['得', '到', '取', '得', '收', '到', '拿', '到', '获', '得']
pinyin_word = ['dédào', 'qǔdé', 'shōudào', 'nádào', 'huòdé']
comb_hanzi_char = ['得到', '取得', '收到', '拿到', '获得']

target = '得到 dédào, 取得 qǔdé, 收到 shōudào, 拿到 nádào, 获得 huòdé.'
res = '得到 dédào, 取得 qǔdé, 收到 shōudào, 拿到 nádào, 获得 huòdé.'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The last line indicating that the assertion passed, and the target has been met.

Comment: ok, thank you for that solution.
Is it possible to use Python + zhon together with Libreofice Writer?

You see, there are some formatting in the text file (italics, bold). I am not sure if these would survive the change to a plain text file (which I assume Python would require as input)?

Comment: Initially I assumed that the problem could be corrected with just a proper regex script.
Of course, I realise now that if outside tools are necessary, then screenshots might also be necessary. There are several thousands of pages this material, so a script is really necessary. Likewise, it's not really practical to copy paste the things into plain text without formatting (that would defeat the purpose of trying to automate things).

Comment: Yes, you can use: https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/sbasic/python/main0000.html   and https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/49125/detailed-tutorial-regarding-libreoffice-to-python-macro-writing-especially-for-calc/